# Coordinate free method of finding geodesics on general surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

We can write the arc length of a space curve as:

$$ L(\gamma) = \int_{0}^t \sqrt{\dot{\gamma} \cdot \dot{\gamma} } dt$$

By binomial theorem and algebra, we can find the variation of $L$ :
$$ \delta L = \int_0^t \frac{\delta  \dot{\gamma} \cdot \dot{\gamma} }{\sqrt{ \dot{\gamma} \cdot \dot{\gamma}} } dt (*)$$

Where $ d \gamma$ is the variation of coordinates I put on the curve, $ d \dot{\gamma}$ is the difference in relative velocity between two nearby curves.

I interpret that the relative velocity between $\gamma$ and and a close by curve $\gamma + d \gamma$ to at a point is perpendicular to the tangent vector of $\gamma$.

---

Now, I want to apply this into finding the shortest distance between two points in $R^2$. A simple way to satisfy the integral is that at all points the relative velocity is perpendicular to tangent or zero. It can be intuitively found the answer to this is lines by drawing the variations. We see at each point that that the $ d(\gamma)$ and hence the relative velocity $ d(\dot{\gamma})$ are dot strictly to zero with tangent of line.

[image]

If we are talking about $\gamma$s which belong to the surface a sphere, we see it's a great circle as with a little bit of drawing we see the result I found is true

[image]

Consider a great circle on the sphere, consider a circle nearby to it , if you compute the relative velocity (/relative direction of tangent vector) we see it points in a direction perpendicular to the tangent directions of the great circle.(**)

---

My questions on this approach:

*: Is this equation correct for curves on all kind of surfaces?

**: On further thought, I am actually do this vector subtraction by considering the tangent vectors of sphere exist in $\mathbb{R^3}$ rather than in the tangent space. This seems intuitively correct to me, but will this cause any conceptual issues?

Has this approach been done before, if so what is it's name?

Comment: I cannot comment on the approach, as I don't understand the statement you're trying to prove. But the starting point of what you're describing is related to the calculus of variations (and the formula for $\delta L$ is called the first variation). The problem with subtracting vectors from neighboring tangent spaces can be "solved" by working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but also intrinsically, by parallel transport along a chosen curve.

Comment: @Michal Miskiewicz informally the idea is there is curves drawn on a surface , between two points what is the characterization of the curve on the surface such that the curve length between two point is minimized

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a quite standard approach to geodesics. You could look up chapter 5.4 in Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* or chapter 1.5 in Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*.