# When can I extremize the integral of $ds^2$ instead of $ds$ for finding geodesics?

Tags: differential-geometry

In my general relativity classes, it was common practice to extremize the integral $\int \left( \frac{ds}{d \lambda} \right)^2 d \lambda$ instead of $\int \frac{ds}{d \lambda} d \lambda$ when finding the geodesic, where $\lambda$ is the parametrization of the curve and $ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^{\nu}dx^{\mu}$. But when I tried to do this when trying to find the geodesic equation on the surface $z=x^2 - y^2$ which has line element $ds^2 = (1 + 4x^2)dx^2 + (1 + 4y^2)dy^2 - 8xy dx dy$, I got different differential equations by following the two different methods.

So my question is, what are the conditions under which I can extremize the integral of $ds^2$ instead of $ds$ to get the same result?

Comment: You can always look at the energy functional instead of the length functional. The problem is the presence of the cross term $8xy\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y$, which requires extra work to deal with, The discussion [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019003/finding-christoffel-symbols-using-via-variational-method) is probably relevant.

Comment: I had asked a something related [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351454/coordinate-free-method-of-finding-geodesics-on-general-surfaces)